# Forma correta de instalar o Laravel no Linux

Tags: laravel, linux, composer

Estou iniciando no Framework Laravel e estou tendo alguns problemas com a instalação no Linux.
Fiz a instalação pelo composer usando o comando **php composer.phar global require "laravel/installer"**, setei no $PATH o caminho **export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"** e executei o comando **laravel new blog** que depois de rodar mostra no console o texto "Crafting application...
sh: 1: composer: not found
Application ready! Build something amazing.", ao rodar o comando **php artisan serve** ele mostra no browser o erro "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Depois disso tentei criar o projeto de outra forma com o comando **php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog**, iniciei o server e ele carregou no browser sem dar erro.

Como faço para criar um projeto usando o comando 'laravel new proj' de forma que não de erro na criação do projeto e ao iniciar o server ?

**Estou usando php 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem o composer.phar setado nas variáveis de ambiente também?

Tente adicionar o executável do composer para ter acesso global no terminal, algo como:

```
cp /seu/caminho/composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

E veja se teve efeito, tentando executar na linha de comando

```
composer -v
```

Isso deve mostrar a versão do composer utilizada

Comment: Fiz o CP e funcionou. Obrigado.